# xmllint validation succeeds on invalid input

Tags: xml, xsd, xmllint

Why does xmllint not report validation failure for the following xsd and xml ?

t.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="letter">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="([a-z])+"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

t.xml

```
 <letter></letter>
```

$ ./xmllint --schema t.xsd t.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<letter/>
t1.xml validates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input does not look valid to me (Mark O'Connor says it's valid, but I  don't see any argument to that effect, just a bald statement).  Equally to the point, it doesn't look valid to Xerces J or to Saxon EE.

The XSD support in xmllint is known to be a bit spotty, but mostly that means that there are parts of the spec that aren't supported; this looks more like a straightforward bug in the regex routine.  I see several unresolved regex bugs in the [gnome bugtracker for libxml](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?product=libxml2); perhaps this is related.  I've opened a [new bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690846) with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The input is valid. You need to add an additional restriction on length.... Call it a "feature" of XML Schema :-)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="letter">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="([a-z])+"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## Update

Revised the schema as follows and then it appears to work as you're expecting

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="letter">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-z]+"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: But why does the pattern itself not work ? Does '+' mean 1 or more already ?

Comment: @user511274 Answer revised

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. But my question really is what's wrong with my original pattern. Is it possible that xmllint has a bug ?

Comment: @user511274 Perhaps it is a bug, but I don't understand why you're specifying brackets in your regular expression. My personal rule is to keep regex's as simple as possible.